# How to find the 3 intersections (yes, not 2)of normal distribution and cauchy distribution？Using matlab

Tags: python, matlab, statistics

How to find the 3 intersections (yes, not 2)of normal distribution and cauchy distribution？Using matlab plz plz plz plz

I could only find two of them (origin-symmetric ones)by using matlab

Comment: One at 0 and two at +-2 ?

Comment: Why the `python` tag?

Comment: %but the result of my code is 2, why?%mu = 0; 
sigma = pi/2; 
x0 = 0; 
gamma = 1; 

x = -10:0.01:10;
y1 = normpdf(x, mu, sigma);
y2 = (1/pi)*gamma./(gamma^2 + (x-x0).^2);
plot(x, y1, 'b-', x, y2, 'r-');


tol = 1e-4; 
idx = find(abs(y1-y2) < tol);
n = length(idx);


disp([num2str(n)]);

Answer (score 0):

using **InterX** function from file exchange:

```
mu = 0;
sigma = pi/2;
x0 = 0;
gamma = 1;
x = -10:0.01:10;
y1 = normpdf(x, mu, sigma);
y2 = (1/pi)*gamma./(gamma^2 + (x-x0).^2);
plot(x, y1, 'b-', x, y2, 'r-');
c1=[y1;x]; %requested format to use the InterX
c2=[y2;x];
p=InterX(c1,c2); %first row is y values of intersections, second row x values
[~,noI]=size(p); %noI is the number of intersections
```

you can find the InterX function here: https://ch.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22441-curve-intersections?s_tid=ta_fx_results